# The convex hull of Schur polynomial evaluations

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, convex-polytopes, schur-functions

Let $r\leq n$ and $d$ be positive integers. A *probability vector* is a vector of non-negative entries that sum to 1. For each probability vector $\lambda$ of length $n$, let

$$s(\lambda)=(\dim[\pi] \cdot s_{\pi}(\lambda))_{\substack{\pi \vdash d}},$$

where $\pi \vdash d$ means that $\pi$ is an integer partition of $d$, $[\pi]$ denotes the irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{S}_d$ indexed by $\pi$, and $s_{\pi} (\lambda)$ is the Schur polynomial indexed by $\pi$ evaluated at $\lambda$. It can be checked that $s(\lambda)$ is a probability vector.

**Question:** Consider the probability vector

$$ t = \left(\frac{1}{\sum_{ \pi \vdash d, \ell(\pi)\leq r } s_{\pi}(1^n)^2}\right) \big(s_{\pi}(1^n)^2\big)_{ \pi \vdash d, \ell(\pi)\leq r },$$

where $\ell(\pi)$ is the number of integers appearing in the integer partition $\pi$. Is it true that $t$ is in the convex hull of the $s(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ ranges over all probability vectors containing at most $r$ non-zero entries?

The answer is trivially yes when $r=1$.

**Notes:** The dimension of $[\pi]$ can be computed using the [Hook-Length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) and the Schur polynomials can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial).

Comment: Is there some particular motivation for this question? It has the flavor of the kind of asymptotic representation theory studied by the Russian school (characters of $S_\infty$, Edrei-Thoma theorem, etc.), but I realize it is a question about finite $n$.

Comment: Where does $r$ appear except the bound for $\ell(\pi)$? It sounds suspicious that if you increase $r$, i. e., add new terms to your vector $s(\lambda)$, it remains a probability vector

Comment: This might be related to Gelfand-Tsetlin polytopes: https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/gtpatterns.htm

Comment: @FedorPetrov Good catch, thanks! There shouldn't be a bound on $\ell(\pi)$ in the definition of $s(\lambda)$. The fact that this is a probability vector can be found e.g. in Proposition 2.16 [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.05028.pdf) (this fact was earlier observed by Its, Tracy, and Widom). I have edited the question.

Comment: @SamHopkins If we let $X_r \subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n) \times \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ be the variety of matrices of rank at most $r$, then a positive answer to this question would imply that the (normalized) orthogonal projection onto $I(X_r)_d^{\perp} \subseteq S^d(\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)$ can be written as a convex combination of terms of the form $(uu^*)^{\otimes d}$, where $u \in \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$ is a unit vector of rank at most $r$ (in fact I think the two questions are equivalent).

Comment: @SamHopkins In general I am interested in when this can be done for an arbitrary projective variety $X$. It can be done if $I(X)_d^{\perp}$ is a Cartan power (e.g. the Segre or Grassmannian varieties), because then it is an irreducible representation of the local unitary group.

Comment: @SamHopkins Correction: $X_r \subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then this is false. Since you want $t$ to live in the same vector space as the $s(\lambda)$'s, I am assuming that the vector $t$ has zero coordinates at each $\pi \vdash d, \ell(\pi)> r$.

Taking $d=3, r=2, n=6$ and indexing the vectors in $\mathbb C^3$ as $(x_{(3)}, x_{(2,1)}, x_{(1,1,1)})$ gives us the vectors
$$s(\lambda)=(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2, 2\lambda_1\lambda_2, 0)$$
and
$$t=(\frac{16}{41}, \frac{25}{41}, 0)$$
Now, the convex hull of the $s(\lambda)$'s is given by the family of vectors $(a, 1-a, 0)$ with $\frac{1}{2}\le a\le 1$, so $t$ is not contained in this convex hull.

---

All that being said, the answer is *positive* for the special case $r=n$, where the probability measure induced by $t$ is (a specialization of) a Schur measure on partitions as studied by Okounkov. This is known to induce a harmonic function on the Young graph and therefore is in the convex hull of the $s(\lambda)$'s (known as *central measures*) by the Edrei-Thoma machinery that was mentioned by Sam above in the comments.